# Is is possible to embed 2 or more style sheets in one link tag?

Tags: html, css

Web developers have to use `<link>` tag in embedding a CSS style sheet into a web page. Sometimes when managing styles, developers break down their style code into several style sheets to gain maximum code re-usability and efficiency.

However a html file or even a css file should reduce its size as possible as smaller files load quickly into user devices. When linking several style sheets, many tutorials show this way.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet3.css">
```

But the size of the html file can be reduced if all 3 style sheets can be embed using one link tag like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css stylesheet2.css stylesheet3.css">
```

Is this possible? Does browsers support embedding several style sheets in one link tag?

Comment: No, but you could concatenate all your files in one file.

Comment: To add on to what @AmauryHanser said. To concatenate the files is a great idea. You can do it manually once off, but if the project grows, you can use a thing called a `packager`/`bundler`. This is pretty much what most modern web apps use. Depending on your project, Webpack, parceljs, gulp, bower... etc, will work for you.

Comment: @RohanBüchner I agree. In my workflow, I use gulp to concatenate and minify my files. This way, one can keep its sources untouched and upload the smallest file on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible to include multiple files in *one* `<link>` tag.

In your CSS-file, you can daisy-chain them into another file however using `@import`.

Lets say you have these files:

```
style.css
table.css
button.css
```

You can then in `style.css` do:

```
<!-- Including one css file into other -->
@import "table.css";
@import "button.css";
```

And in HTML import them all like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

However you can use popular and powerful bundling tools such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) that will bundle both your Javascript and CSS files.

Comment: Of course @import is 7 characters long while the part <link rel='stylesheet' ...> is more longer than that. However as in Amaury Hanser's answer in the comments, concatenate all style sheet into one file in the final code is more efficient. Because it even doesn't require a '@import'.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No. because `href` attribute of `link` tag must be a URL string so you can't reference multiple URL.

But this kind of optimization can take place into your build system. In these build pipelines you can have multiple `css` or `js` file in your development environment but in production you may have only one optimized (chunked or minified) file for each.

Check out [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) as a beginner-friendly web application bundler

Also for more advance options you can use 
https://gulpjs.com
or
https://webpack.js.org

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to define more than one file in a single "href" attribute. 
Also for each "href" there is its own relation define in the "rel" attribute.

you can read more about the link attributes on the following link:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to add two or more stylesheets with one link tag.

Answer (score -2):

no it's not possible,
If you do, you will receive a link error you can see it in network tab in chrome
[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68jH5.jpg)